# cURL produced cookie not working when next page has same URL as the login page

Tags: javascript, curl, cookies

As a preface, I am a researcher in genomics and am not experienced as a developer, so go easy on me. I think my problem is something that others would run into when trying to call cookies to get to a second webpage that has the same URL as the first, login page.

Background:
I need to use cURL in a linux environment to access data on a 3rd web page, but I can't get past the first 2 webpages. Page 1 is the log in page, and page 2 is a terms and conditions page with accept or do not accept buttons.

Page 1: The login page
The URL is **https://siteURL.com/login/**

The html for the Username box indicates: name="j_username" 
The html for the password box indicates: type="password" name="j_password"
And then there is some code that indicates a login graphic and says onClick="return validate(this.form)"  which I think is why I don't have to indicate a submit button.

When I use the command **curl -d "j_username=MyName&j_password=MyPassword" -c cookie.txt https://siteURL.com/login/**   I get to the next page (I didn't have to simulate the click of a button).

Page 2: Terms and conditions page
This second page contains a terms and conditions description with accept or do not accept buttons. This second page has the same URL as the first page (https://siteURL.com/login/), and the html code for the I ACCEPT button indicates: button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name=btnAccept style="width:150px">I ACCEPT< /button>

You'd think I would be able to, at that point, call the cookie that I made with the first curl command to get back to that second page and click the "I ACCEPT" button:
**curl -b cookie.txt -d "btnAccept=I%20ACCEPT" https://queries.uscdcb.com/login/**

Instead, I get to what looks to be a failed login page, as if I was on the first page. Does this have to do with the fact that the first and second page share the same URL, so that I can't really point to the second (terms and conditions page) with my second cURL command?

Again, I am not a coder/developer. I've been at this for a few days and pulling up very little on this specific problem, though I've read a lot of basic cURL, and cURL cookie related documents and forum discussions. I'm hoping this is easily solved and is really just linked with my inexperience with all of this. Any suggestions would put me in a better place than I'm currently in. Thanks!

Comment: could be a million different things, for example hidden fields for the login (like a csrf token) - still, could you contact me on facebook? (see my profile), if i'm bored and have free time, i could probably help you figure it out, and im bored